# Error during deploy from visual studio to analysis server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, business-intelligence

I'm connected to analysis server:localhost\sqlr2.
I'm using windows authentication,so user name and password are all grayed out.
I'm trying to deploy a project from Visual Studio BI to SQL Server 2008R2 analysis server and get the following errors:

```
Error   1   Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.        0   0   
Error   2   OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login timeout expired; HYT00; A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ; 08001.       0   0   
Error   3   Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Max Min Manufacturing DM', Name of 'Max Min Manufacturing DM'.      0   0
```

Comment: Please do not edit your questions to remove all the content, as doing so means the existing answers no longer make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your datasource is set up wrong. When you process, what server is the cube pointed at? What account does SSAS run under? How have you set up the connection string in the datasource? Are you seeing failed login attempts in the SQL Server logs?

```
Error 2 OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login timeout expired; HYT00; 
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. 
Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections.
```

I'd focus on this. I assume you must be able to connect to SQL Server in Visual Studio to build your cube, so I guess Analysis Services doesn't have permissions. Check your connection strings.

You say you're using Windows Authentication, so does the service accounts that Analysis Services runs under have access to the required database?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my experience with this error and how I discovered the solution. 
Hope it helps!

http://afsawaf.blogspot.com/2013/08/ole-db-error-ole-db-or-odbc-error.html

---Thanks @kleopatra for the advice.
In my case I was connecting with a wrong provider, I was trying to connect using **SQL Server Native Client 11.0** to MS SQL Server 2005 DB which caused my similar problem.
When I reverted to **version 10.0**, worked perfectly!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.